# How to determine the amount of memory location available

Tags: memory

My lecturer pops up with this question today. However, I'm new to this and I have no idea what it is about, please help me.

"Suppose your microcomputer memory address is 16 bits wide, how many locations that it can have, assuming each memory location is 8 bits wide. Express the memory capacity in bytes, megabytes, gigabytes and terabytes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't ask for help with homework on SO.
None the less, you would work it out like this:

If a memory address is encoded in 16 bits, that means you can point to 2^16 units of memory before you cant count any higher:

```
0000000000000000
0000000000000001
0000000000000010
...
1111111111111111
```

Which is a number you should know off the top of your head as 65536 - the largest integer you can store in 2 bytes :)

So if you can point to 65536 blocks of space, and each unit of space is apparently 8 bits (1 byte), how many bytes, megabytes, gigabytes and terabytes is that?

Comment: +1 Good answer - though I think the OP is going to hate you for it, as it's "more confusing" than the lecturer's original question - it will force someone to start their research career, probably on Google  ;-)